# Laravel Has Undefined Constant 'App\App\projects

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have created a model called company and projects, I need to show projects under a company. The company is showing fine, but when I added a project relation to the model, it displays an error. I am a newbie to Laravel.

> Undefined constant 'App\App\projects' (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\testdrive\resources\views\companies\show.blade.php)
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\testdrive\app\company.php

**Model**

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class company extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'user_id'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\User);
    }

    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(App\projects);
    }
}
```

**show.blade.php**

```php
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Jumbotron -->
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>{{$company->name}}</h1>
            <p class="lead">{{$company->description}}</p>
        </div>

        <!-- Example row of columns -->
        <div class="row">
            @foreach($company->projects as $projects)
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <h2>{{$projects->name}}</h2>
                    <p class="text-danger">{{$projects->description}} </p>
                    <p>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/projects/{{$projects->id}}" role="button">View Project</a>
                    </p>

                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: try this return `$this->hasMany(App\projects::class);`

Comment: show us how you are trying to use it in show.blade.

Comment: @Galabin Vasilev its added

Comment: `return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); return $this->hasMany('App\projects');` Don't forget the quotes.

Comment: Galabin Vasilev  It worked thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a typo! namespaces should be strings:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\projects');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `class` keyword in your model

```
  class company extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable=[
        'name',
        'description',
        'user_id'

    ];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class);
}

public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany(App\projects::class);
}

}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Either pass class of the model or it's namespace within questions

```
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class); //or $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function projects()
{
  return $this->hasMany(App\Project::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using quotes to reference the model as mentioned above. 
It might also be necessary to define the namespace of your class.

Sidenote: it's also a Laravel naming convention to use PascalCase for classnames (ie. Company, WetCamel, FooBarClass)

```
namespace App\Company;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Company extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'user_id'

    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Projects');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use '' this to call the model.

Correct your syntax as:

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\projects');
}
```

Comment: How is this answer any different from the accepted answer?